# Chrome dev tools does not highlight active css class

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

In the past, when I inspected css using dev tools in Chrome, it would highlight the active class, now it doesn't - has that feature gone away? Is there a way to turn it back on? It's still on all other modern browsers.

The screen shots below show inspecting a button with class `btn-primary`

Chrome just shows all classes equal color, font weight etc, the Firefox screenshot show how Chrome used to show it.

[image]

[image]

Comment: https://crbug.com/1219153 fixed in Chrome 93 so in [less than a month](https://chromiumdash.appspot.com/schedule) it'll be in stable channel.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's a recognised Chrome bug which is fixed ready for release within 30 days of 06 Aug 21